Creating a sidebar that follows and reaches out to mouse
I recently saw this [sidebar][1] that follows the mouse and "reaches out" to the mouse when it gets close enough and I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to implement it? I saw this [post][2] with the answer to have a menu that follows the mouse, but I'm unsure of where to go next from here. I really like how the example has the menu sort of "grow" to where the mouse is and have it come out of the rectangular sidebar.
[1]: https://codemyui.com/gooey-sidebar-stretch-menu-concept/
[2]: Sidebar hide/show button that follows cursor mouse?
<div class="A"></div>

.A {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

var posY;

$(document).mousemove( function(e) { 
   posY = e.pageY;
    $('.A').css({'top': posY});
});


Let's manipulate SVG that I created using this website. Basically you want to learn about Cubic-Bezier curve because I just randomly demonstrated changing some values in the SVG.
Here's a quick explanation for the d attribute of the <path>:

M = move to x, y
L = line to x, y
C = cubic bezier to x, y with control points at x1, y1 and x2, y2
Z = go back to start



const svg = document.getElementById('wavySvg');
const path = document.getElementById('wavyPath');

function updatePath(mouseX, mouseY) {
  const height = 320;
  const width = 1440;

  const d = `
      M 0,592
      C ${240 - mouseY},139,180,${125 - mouseX / width * 100 },720,${80 + mouseY / height * 100}
      C ${600 + mouseX / 2},475,1200,117,${1320 + mouseX / width * 100},138.7
      L 1440, ${mouseY}
      L 1440,720
      L 0,720
      Z
    Z
  `;

  path.setAttribute('d', d);
}

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseX = e.offsetX
  const mouseY = e.offsetY
  updatePath(mouseX, mouseY);
});

updatePath(0, 0)
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#wavyPath {
  transition: d 0.25s ease;
}

#wavySvg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<svg id="wavySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 720">
  <path id="wavyPath" fill="#0099ff" d=""></path>
</svg> Move your mouse



UPDATE
Another example hopefully better and simpler.
This time using:

Q = quadratic curve to x, y with control point at x1, y1



const svg = document.getElementById('wavySvg');
const path = document.getElementById('wavyPath');
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

function updatePath(mouseX, mouseY) {
  const d = `
      M 0,${height / 2}
      Q ${mouseX * 2 - width / 2},${mouseY - height / 2} ${width},${height / 2}
      L ${width},${height}
      L 0,${height}
      Z
  `;
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  path.setAttribute('d', d);
}

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseX = e.offsetX
  const mouseY = e.offsetY
  updatePath(mouseX, mouseY);
});

svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  path.classList.add("animated")
  updatePath(width / 2, height);
});

svg.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => path.classList.remove("animated"), 250)
});


updatePath(width / 2, height);
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animated {
  transition: d 0.25s ease;
}

#wavySvg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<svg id="wavySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
  <path id="wavyPath" fill="#0099ff" d="" class="animated"></path>
</svg> Move your mouse



